# Finding connectedness from a list of nodes and a list of edges

Tags: python, graph-theory, hierarchical-clustering

(tl;dr)

> Given a collection of nodes defined as a dictionary of points, and a collection of edges defined as a dictionary of key tuples, is there an algorithm in python to easily find consecutive segments?

(context:)

I have two files that model segments of a road network.

[Nodes.txt](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/heltonbiker/ca043f8ee191db5bf8349b1b7af0394c/raw/nodes.txt):

```
1;-5226574;-3118329 # latitude and longitude as integers (multiplied by 1e5)
2;-5226702;-3118330
3;-5226750;-3118332
4;-5226793;-3118338
...
```

[Edges.txt](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/heltonbiker/ca043f8ee191db5bf8349b1b7af0394c/raw/edges.txt):

```
1;1;2
2;3;5
3;23;345
4;23;11
...
```

Each edge represents an (indexed) link between two nodes, by the node indexes.

A sub-section of the generated network is plotted below:

[image]

As you can see, the overwhelming majority of nodes is a "simple" node, meaning it is in the middle of a road segment and belongs to exactely two edges. On the other hand, there are "special" nodes, meaning they represent a bifurcation, or crossroad, because it belongs to three or more edges.

Currently, I have a collection of isolated road segments, but I would like to have each road segment between two special nodes defined as a *sequence* of nodes. It makes everything much faster to plot, to measure distances, etc., and it also allows me to represent each node sequence as a "super edge" linking two special nodes, thus simplifying the topology.

I can easily imagine some brute-force way to do that, but the amount of nodes is relatively high, and I don't have a theoretical background that points me a way to solve this.

UPDATE:

I have [created a gist](https://gist.github.com/heltonbiker/ca043f8ee191db5bf8349b1b7af0394c) with my raw data. Each line represents a road as a sequence of points (lat, lon), and the roads overlap a lot. My goal is to generate the dictionaries for nodes and links from this "list of roads" in the file.

You can use the following python script to access the content:

```
with open('RawRoads.txt') as roadsFile:
    for line in roadsFile.readlines():
        road = [tuple(map(lambda x:int(float(x)*1e5), coord.split(','))) for coord in line.strip().split(' ')]
```

or else:

```
import urllib

url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/heltonbiker/ca043f8ee191db5bf8349b1b7af0394c/raw/RawRoads.txt"

lines = urllib.urlopen(url).readlines() 
for line in lines:
    # you got the idea
```

Comment: When you say the quantity is "relatively high", how high is that?  From what you've posted, I suspect that you're not in the giga-node range in which I sometimes work ... :-)  I think I can swot up a decent O(N^2) algorithm with a low constant.  Do you have a data set you can throw at us?  Just the edge list would do for these purposes.

Comment: @Prune The nodes and edges are generated from Map Direction services (Google in this case) and tend to increase a lot quite soon, but still not in the giganode range (I plan to partition the datasets if they grow that large). I'll try to give you a good dataset to play with as soon as I can, thanks!

Comment: @Prune - I'm updating the question with a Gist. I'm also posting my raw data, because the structure for nodes and files that I posted is intended, I'm not getting it right for now. Just look at my update.

Comment: @Prune my Gist now has actual `nodes.txt` and `edges.txt` files generated from `RoadRaw.txt`.

Comment: Thanks.  Working on it.  My tracking doesn't handle a couple of corner cases ... yet.

Comment: @Prune, you're great! Maybe you find [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1819028/27435) i've made today interesting. Also, I discovered that what I want is something like "all paths whose extremities are nodes of order larger than two, and whose inner nodes have order 2 or less".

Comment: That's how I'm tackling it.  Note, however, that this will not get you all roads: a road that runs off the edge of the map, or a dead end, leaves you an endpoint of order 1.  Our endpoints are nodes of order != 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's not get too brutish.  I think we can do well by building a simple  list of lists, such that **edge[i]** is a list of up to three elements, the nodes to which node **i** is connected.  If your node numbers are dense and start near 0, you can use a list; in case they're not, I'll use a directory.

I build a list from edges.txt in the form of

edge_list = 
[(1,2),
 (2,3), 
 (3,5),
 (2, 23), 
(23,345), 
(23,11), ...]

Now build the two-way edge reference directory:

Next, identify the special nodes, those with an order other than 2: intersections and map edges.  Then we pick one and build a segment until we hit another.

```
# Dictionary of edges, indexed in both directions by node number.
edge = {}

# Ingest the data and build teh dictionary
with open("edges.txt") as efile:
    for line in efile:
        eid, src, dst = line.strip().split(';')
        src = int(src)
        dst = int(dst)

        for key, val in [(src, dst), (dst, src)] :
            if key in edge:
                edge[key].append(val)
            else:
                edge[key] = ([val])
print "edge dictionary has entries:", len(edge)

# Identify endpoint nodes: order other than 2
end_ct = 0
print "Endpoint Nodes"
endpoint = []
for src, dst in edge.iteritems():
    if len(dst) != 2:
        print len(dst), src, dst
        endpoint.append(src)
        end_ct += len(dst)
print end_ct, "road ends"

atlas = []    # List of roads, each a list of nodes

# Build roads between the identified endpoints
# Pick the first endpoint in the remaining list.
# Move to the first-listed adjacent node.
# Keep going until we hit another node on the endpoint list.
while len(endpoint) > 0:
    here = endpoint[0]
#   print "Road starting at", here, edge[here]

    # Pick a first step and consume the edge
    next = edge[here].pop(0)
    edge[next].remove(here)
    road = [here, next]

    # If that's the last connection to the node, remove that node from the endpoints list.
    if len(edge[here]) == 0:
        del endpoint[0]
        del edge[here]
    # Special case for a one-segment road; endpoint entry of "next" is removed after the loop
    if len(edge[next]) == 0:
        del edge[next]

    # Consume edges until we reach another endpoint.
    debug = False
    while next not in endpoint:
        here = next
        next = edge[here].pop(0)
        edge[next].remove(here)
        road.append(next)
        if len(edge[next]) == 0:
            del edge[next]
#           print "removing node", next

    if next not in edge:
        endpoint.remove(next)
#       print "removing endpoint", next

    print "\nRoad from", road[0], "to", road[-1], ':\n\t', road
    atlas.append(road)

print "\n", len(atlas), "roads built"
# print "edge dictionary still has entries:", len(edge)
```

EDIT FROM OP:

It worked, it's fast and correct, and I find it deserves a visualization:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for road in atlas:
    path = [nodesdict[i] for i in road]
    lons, lats = zip(*path)
    plt.plot(lons, lats)

plt.grid()
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer! I'm gonna check them as soon as I get home from work. I hope not to spoil too much of this possible implementation, but I have discovered how to use [`networkx`](https://networkx.github.io/) to build and analyze the graph, and all the needed functionality seems to be right there, and it's quite fast! Anyway, I'm gonna test your answer and accept it if it more or less works!

Comment: Let's hope ... I write it up last evening, but forgot to hit "post".  It's not an elegant solution -- it's quite low-tech (in terms of Python features) and would work more effectively to build roads while reading the input, since they tend to come in sequence.  However, it's fast enough that the limiting factor is I/O time.